# Display li element caption in two lines, to fit into max-width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Jsfiddle as,
     https://jsfiddle.net/9qyv03u3/

How can i break the `li` caption string into two lines so that they will fit into a maximum width?

In jsfiddle, the menu items are placed in a single line but inside my 50% width container in firefox, it gets rendered as,

[image: Jumbled menus]

This will lead to user pressing the wrong menu option. So, i prefer all menu options horizontally placed like,

```
   Save & Run  | Run saved |  Run selected  |
      suite    |   suite   |      tests     |
```

Comment: Neither flexbox nor css tables needed. https://jsfiddle.net/9qyv03u3/7/

Comment: love you so much, for the extra tip - `li:last-of-type {
    border-right-width: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the list items as table cells. You may need to tweak the margins and paddings a bit, but this way the items will be next to each other always.

```css
ul{
  display: table; 
  width: 20em;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  list-style: None;
  height: 30px;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  padding-right : 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Questions</li>
  <li>Tags liek bla blo foo bar bak nam plo and sni</li>
  <li>Users</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making the `ul` a flexbox:

```
ul { 
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
ul { 
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px verdana;
}

li {
  margin: 20px 30px 10px 0;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  padding-right : 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Save & Run suite</li>
  <li>Run saved suite</li>
  <li>Run selected tests</li>
</ul>
```

… or by making each `li` a `table-cell`:

```
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
ul { 
  width: 20em;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  list-style: none;
  font: 14px verdana;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 20px 30px 10px 0;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  padding-right : 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Save & Run suite</li>
  <li>Run saved suite</li>
  <li>Run selected tests</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS tables I would suggest.

```css
ul {
  width: 20em;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  list-style: None;
  height: 30px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Questions & Answers</li>
  <li>Tags</li>
  <li>Users</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property to define CSS columns. This is a quick and easy way of achieving the desired effect.

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  width: 25em;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  padding: 1.5em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  list-style: None;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  border-right-style: dotted;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Save & Run suite</li>
  <li>Run saved suite</li>
  <li>Run selected tests</li>
</ul>
```